# How to evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-\alpha\cos{\theta}}{r'^3}d\theta$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Let $P$ be a fixed point inside a circle with radius $r$ and $Q$ a non-fixed point on its perimeter as shown below, and let $\alpha=\frac xr$

[image: pic]

Is there any closed-form solution for the following integral?
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-\alpha\cos{\theta}}{{r'}^{3}}d\theta$$
I tried Wolfram-Alpha without any luck. It doesn't look similar to any form of the integrals I have ever seen before. I appreciate if anybody gives it a try.

Comment: $r'^3$ is not a function of $\theta$ right? So this is just the integral of a constant +  cosine.

Comment: @Shashi Are you sure $r'$ is not a function of $\theta$? Look again at the picture

Comment: Sorry my bad I misunderstood it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall that
$$
r'=\sqrt{r^2+x^2-2rx\cos \theta}
$$ we are then looking for
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-\alpha\cos{\theta}}{{r'}^{3}}d\theta
\\&=\frac1{r^3}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-\alpha\cos{\theta}}{\left(1+\alpha^2-2\alpha\cos \theta\right)^{3/2}}d\theta
\\&=\frac1{r^3}\frac1{(1+\alpha^2)^{3/2}}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-\alpha\cos{\theta}}{\left(1-\frac{2\alpha}{1+\alpha^2}\cos \theta\right)^{3/2}}d\theta
\\&=\frac1{r^3}\frac1{(1+\alpha^2)^{3/2}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2\:\Gamma\big(n+\frac32\big)}{\Gamma\big(n+1\big)\Gamma\big(\frac12\big)}\cdot\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\cos^n{\theta}-\alpha\cos^{n+1}{\theta}\right)d\theta\cdot\left(\frac{2\alpha}{1+\alpha^2} \right)^n
\end{align}
$$ setting $a=\dfrac{2\alpha}{1+\alpha^2}$, $0<a<1$, one may then use [Wallis' integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals)
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^n{\theta}\:d\theta= 2\cdot\frac{\Gamma\big(\frac12\big)\Gamma(\tfrac{n+1}{2})}{\Gamma\big(\tfrac{n}{2}+1\big)}
$$ to obtain
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2\:\Gamma\big(n+\frac32\big)}{\Gamma\big(n+1\big)\Gamma\big(\frac12\big)}\cdot\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\cos^n{\theta}-\alpha\cos^{n+1}{\theta}\right)d\theta\cdot a^n
\\\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4\:\Gamma\big(n+\frac32\big)\Gamma(\tfrac{n+1}{2})}{\Gamma\big(n+1\big)\Gamma\big(\tfrac{n}{2}+1\big)} \cdot a^n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4\:\Gamma\big(n+\frac52\big)\Gamma(\tfrac{n}{2}+1)}{\Gamma\big(n+2\big)\Gamma\big(\tfrac{n}{2}+\tfrac32\big)} \cdot a^n
\\\\&=\frac{4\mathrm{E}\left(\frac{2 a}{1+a}\right)}{(1-a)\sqrt{1+a}}-\frac{4\alpha \mathrm{K}\left(\frac{2 a}{1+a}\right)}{a\sqrt{1+a}}+\frac{4\alpha\mathrm{E}\left(\frac{2 a}{1+a}\right)}{a(1-a)\sqrt{1+a}}
\end{align}
$$ where we have used elliptic integrals [$\mathrm{E}(r):=\mathrm{E}(\tfrac\pi2,r)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind) and [$\mathrm{K}(r):=\mathrm{K}(\tfrac\pi2,r)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind).

Finally,

> $$
> r^3(1+\alpha^2)^{3/2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-\alpha\cos{\theta}}{{r'}^{3}}d\theta=\frac{4\mathrm{E}\left(\frac{2 a}{1+a}\right)}{(1-a)\sqrt{1+a}}-\frac{4\alpha \mathrm{K}\left(\frac{2 a}{1+a}\right)}{a\sqrt{1+a}}+\frac{4\alpha\mathrm{E}\left(\frac{2 a}{1+a}\right)}{a(1-a)\sqrt{1+a}}.
> $$

Comment: What expansion have you got?

Comment: $$(1-\alpha\cos\theta)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(\cos\theta)\alpha^n\right)^3$$

Comment: @polfosol See my edit.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for trying

Comment: @polfosol Another route.

Comment: This is great :) But I didn't get the part where $\int$ turned into $\sum$. Also the link to Wallis integral does not work

Comment: @polfosol One may use the binomial theorem to get $\frac{1}{\left(1-z\right)^{3/2}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2\:\Gamma\big(n+\frac32\big)}{\Gamma\big(n+1\big)\Gamma\big(\frac12\big)}\cdot z^n$, $|z|<1$. This is how I've turned $\int$ into $\sum$.